# Change property of vue img uploader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to upload my images with this vue.js. i'm using this [plugin](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-upload-multiple-image-component-for-vuejs/) for the task. But I need to change the language. In doc it's said we can change it by using props. And I did,

```
:drag-text='drag_text'
```

Here is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>vue-upload-multiple-image</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="car_ad_others"></div>
        </div>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
             var parent = $('#car_ad_others').parent();
             parent.html('<div id="car-image-upload"><upload-component></upload-component></div>');
             $('#car_ad_others').parent().attr('id', 'car_ad_parent');

             Vue.component('upload-component', {
                 props: ['dragText'],
                 data: function () {
                     return {
                         images: '',
                         uploadImageSuccess: '',
                         beforeRemove: '',
                         editImage: '',
                         dataChange: '',
                         drag_text: 'ddd'
                     };
                 },
                 template: "<div id='my-strictly-unique-vue-upload-multiple-image' style='display: flex; justify-content: center;'><vue-upload-multiple-image :drag-text='drag_text' @upload-success='uploadImageSuccess' @before-remove='beforeRemove' @edit-image='editImage' @data-change='dataChange' :data-images='images'></vue-upload-multiple-image></div>"
             });
             new Vue({el: '#car-image-upload'});
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it didn't got translated and I'm getting this error too,

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did
>   you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make
>   sure to provide the "name" option.

Properties are in this [link](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-upload-multiple-image-component-for-vuejs/#props). And I have simplified my code to show the issue easier. So I cant change the structure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, there's a bug in the library itself. The codepen in the document doesn't seem to respond to props change. About your `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:` warning, somehow this worked for me:

```
    components: {
       'vue-upload-multiple-image': () => import('https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js')
    },
```

and comment `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js"></script>`

I am still trying to figure out how but it should be something related to local registration components vs global registration of the components. I will improve this answer as I come along with better and concrete explanation

Answer (score 1):

try this

:drag-text="drag_text"

:drag-text = "'your text as string'"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).